# Fluentd Plain text output instead of json

Tags: fluentd

Is it possible to have fluentd output logs as it is instead of json, just like tailing with zero modifications.

Please let me know, if there are any output plugins to achieve this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

See following offcial articles:

none section: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail
single_value: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_file#format

Answer (score 0):

"format single_value" in output plugin will do.

```
<match **>
    @type file
    path path-to-file
    format single_value
</match>
```

Ref - https://docs.fluentd.org/formatter/single_value

Comment: If you want your solution to be accepted, you should at least provide explanations and not just only a link to the documentation